# React Native - Error while updating property 'nativeBackgroundAndroid' of a view managed by: RCTView

Tags: react-native

I started getting errors after downloading "@ react-navigation/drawer". I downloaded and uploaded the file again and kept getting errors.

Could you please help?

I shared error screenshots.

```
Stack trace:
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:173:8 in registerError
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
  node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
  node_modules\prop-types\checkPropTypes.js:20:6 in printWarning
  node_modules\prop-types\checkPropTypes.js:82:22 in checkPropTypes
  node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1714:20 in validatePropTypes
  node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1813:21 in createElementWithValidation
  node_modules\@expo\vector-icons\build\createMultiStyleIconSet.js:70:23 in IconClass#render
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12478:21 in finishClassComponent
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12403:43 in updateClassComponent
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19181:22 in beginWork$1
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18085:22 in performUnitOfWork
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18013:38 in workLoopSync
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17977:18 in renderRootSync
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17674:33 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
  [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
  node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17125:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20527:14 in updateContainer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21068:17 in render
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:54:4 in renderApplication
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:213:4 in runApplication
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

[Error's Screenshoots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDm3E.png)

[Error's Screenshoots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8zPZ.jpg)